# How can I set up my email to work properly with Outlook AND Gmail

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, gmail

I recently signed up for [Microsoft Office Business Premium](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-business-premium). They made me change my DNS settings and now mail is REALLY slow to arrive in my Gmail inbox, but is quick enough for Outlook.

What I want is for mail to arrive to both simultaneously.

Comment: I am guessing you are forwarding your email to your Google email address?  What exactly is `Microsoft Office Premium`, I am familar with Office 365 which to my knowlege it the only subscription offered by Microsoft that contains Office in it, not familar with `Microsoft Office Premium`.  A quick google search indicates you mean `Microsoft Office 365 Business Premium` or `Microsoft Office 365 Home Premium` please update your question to provide the require clarification.

Comment: Updated the question to show which product I actually mean, with link.

I think that before I had installed Office, I had done some setup with my DNS to send my email to Gmail